# Looking for an arabic dictionary database

Tags: database, dictionary, arabic

How can I get a database of an arabic dictionary?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This Arabic dictionary is 9 Millions keywords and in source forge:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/arabic-wordlist/
The entire list is validated against Microsoft Word spell checker.

Comment: Wordlist is not a dictionary but thanks nonetheless

Comment: It seems that the file only contains Arabic verbs, which is a huge con.

Answer (score 0):

a possible way is to use google search engine using query like `arabic dictionary "open source" OR free`.. using this technique, i have found e.g. the Arabeyes project, which has english-arabic [wordlist](http://sourceforge.net/projects/arabeyes/files/Wordlist/) in gettext `.po` format.